# Is this just the paint cracks?

Tags: road-bike, chain, frames, dropouts, specialized-bikes

It is on the dropout of my new tarmac, one month old.

The shop owner said "It's normal for this side to crack it might be from the chain"

But when I did test the chain it didn't touch the frame (there got 5mm gap between). But I don't know exactly that when I ride.

So has this happen to anyone?

And how do I know if my frame has cracked or not?

[image]

Comment: From the look of it it does appear to be simply cracked paint, though it's hard to tell for sure from that single picture -- one would really need to inspect first-hand.  I'm guessing it's due to a combo of overly-thick paint (used to achieve that high gloss) combined with a slightly poor fit for the derailer hanger. It looks like the hanger bumping against the dropout initiated the cracking, and it progressed from there.

Comment: (It is a bit disappointing to have this happen to such an expensive bike -- I assume by "tarmac" you mean a Specialized Tarmac such as the $8000 Dura Ace.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It s-works new tarmac frame set

Comment: The obligatory note is that there are a lot of fake S-Works/similarly high end bikes on the market, so assuming its authentic (the fakes are often sold well below Specialized's price, usually online; they can look pretty good though), I'd be disappointed with this.

Comment: Check the warranty. I think Specialized has a lifetime warranty on the frame.

Comment: If indeed you bought just the frame and then added your own derailer hanger it's likely that you are at fault for using one that dug into the paint at that point.  If it was a factory-installed hanger then I would tend to blame Specialized.

Comment: It looks to me like the derailleur limiting screw is set wrong for that end of the cassette and the chain has perhaps temporarily slipped over on to the frame (bad). However, you'd probably know about this if only you have ridden the bike. Agree with the others though - this does look purely cosmetic, and if it was just the chain then the frame is probably not damaged. However, you need to be super careful if it's carbon.

Comment: This is really interesting as a rider from my club recently bought a Tarmac and had _exactly_ the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a chain jam from a wrongly adjusted rear mechanism. The paint finishes on these bikes tends to be fairly hard and a good smack will chip the paint.

The next question is what's been done to the frame. Without testing, x ray type inspection, history etc. Its impossible to tell. So that just leaves whether you trust it enough not to lay out for a new frame. Me, I'd trust that sort of catch if there is nothing obvious in the carbon layup and it rides ok. Go easy to start, build confidence in it; or not. You decide.