# Carbon fiber crack?

Tags: road-bike, frames

[image]

Bought my first carbon fiber bike last month.  Just found this damage by the rear derailer.  How can I tell if this is just a chip in the paint or of the frame is damaged?  The bike has not been in any crashes.

Comment: Looks like a chip. Usually the drop outs are made of alloy which is then bonded to the carbon frame stays. A chip on top of an alloy drop out is nothing to get too worked up about. Even a chip of paint on carbon may be fine as there is a cosmetic carbon layer over the structural carbon. Damage into the structural carbon is what you need to worry about.

Comment: There is another nearly identical question (though with more extensive damage pictured), posted maybe 2 months ago.  However, I can't find it.

Comment: (Your main problem is that there's not nearly enough grease and grime in that area.  If there were you wouldn't notice the chip.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks [Is this just the paint cracks?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/45775/13174) Not sure this is really a duplicate since, as you say, the damage on the other question is more severe. But maybe somebody could write a reference question along the lines of "I found chipped paint on my rear dropouts -- how do I tell if it's more than cosmetic?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Yeah, that's the one -- virtually identical.  And I don't know a lot about carbon fiber frames, but I have to believe that there is a metal piece embedded in the carbon, in the area of the dropout.

Comment: The RD hanger looks to be too tightly embedded and has worked a chip off the edge.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, it looks like a chip, I wouldn't worry about it except to just keep an eye on it and make sure it doesn't worsen. I mainly wanted to add that not all carbon frames have aluminium drop outs, some have carbon and I'd say that is more and more common on newer frames. I have a 2013 Scott Foil and that has carbon drop outs, so it's not a new thing.